# Find the greatest value among four tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column **Date** with the same name in four tables **Products, Customers, Shops, World** in mysql. what i want to do is that i want to find the **greatest date** in the **DATE COLUMN** of all four tables. I don't want the greatest date of every table but the greatest one in all four tables. I hope you are understanding. Please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most efficient way I can think of would be using the `greatest` function:

```
select greatest(
    (select max(date) from products),
    (select max(date) from customers),
    (select max(date) from shops),
    (select max(date) from world)
) greatest_date
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a47a/1) demo

Comment: +1 Good thinking. The only thing you need to do is to put each select in parentheses. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: +1 Mosty. and thank you peterm a lot. YOur ideas took me out of lots of frustration. Thanks a lot .. :)

Answer (score 3):

This might work:

```
SELECT MAX(Date) as Max_Date
FROM (
   SELECT Date FROM Products
   UNION
   SELECT Date FROM Customers
   UNION
   SELECT Date FROM Shops
   UNION
   SELECT Date FROM World
  ) AS P;
```

Comment: +1 for [Mosty Mostacho](http://stackoverflow.com/users/268273/mosty-mostacho) answer. It is much better than mine

Comment: +1 Thanks for your idea too Eternal-learner. Very much appreciated